# Синхронное выполнение функции возврат с callback

Tags: node.js

Есть объект с данными:

```
obj.user = {
    "10": {
        "500": {
            "rank": "LEADER",
            "nick": "test1"
        },
        "501": {
            "rank": "MEMBER",
            "nick": "test2"
        }
    },
    "20": {
        "500": {
            "rank": "LEADER",
            "nick": "test1"
        }
    }
}
```

Далее функция

```
var userCache = {}
function checkUser(chat, id, callback) {
    if(userCache[id] === undefined) {
        request(apiURL, function(err, res, body) { // возвращается json
            userCache[id] = body;
            console.log(id + " NEW");
            callback();
        })
    }
    else {
        console.log(id + " OLD")
    }
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы в функцию шли элементы с obj.user по очереди и userCache запоминал всё правильно.
Написал вот такой код:

```
Object.keys(obj.user).reduce((promiseChain, chat) => {
    return promiseChain.then(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
        for(var id in obj.user[chat]) {
            checkUser(chat, id, resolve);
        }
    }));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

но он почему-то обрабатывает около 40 юзеров и останавливается.

Comment: где в функции _checkUser_ используется третий параметр, в который ты передаешь `resolve`?

Comment: забыл дописать, извиняюсь. исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае не совсем корректное использование конструктора Promise. Так как `promise` - могут перейти в состояние `resolve`, только один раз, вызов метода `resolve` в цикле ничего не даст.

вместо этого, нужно создать `Promise` на каждой итерации цикла, и затем просто дождаться их всех, с помощью [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Object.keys(obj.user).reduce((promiseChain, chat) => {
    return promiseChain.then(() => {
        var promises = [];
        for(var id in obj.user[chat]) {
            promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => {
                checkUser(chat, id, resolve);
            }));
        }
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: всё равно обрабатываются не все элементы obj.user. После того как первый элемент obj.user вернет всё элементы obj.user[chat ], скрипт прекратит свою работу

Comment: @teamspam, в таком случае очевидно, что один из запросов прерывается, чтобы узнать какой, добавь в метод  then, второй обработчик. который выполнится в случае ошибки.